# Import Android Application into another android Application

Tags: android, android-intent

Sometimes when an application (A) requires another application (B) to carry out some functions, application (B) would have to be imported into application (A). This is in case where the user does not have the application (B) previously installed.

What happens if the phone already has application B installed on its own but the user wants to install application A (which of course has B imported into it)?

Are there going to be any issues experienced?

Thanks

Comment: "having to import the 2nd application into the 1st one in case the user does not have the second application installed previously" -- that is not a recommended approach. The standard approach is to have the 1st application see if the 2nd application is installed, and if not, to lead the user to the Play Store or other distribution point to obtain the 2nd application.

Answer (score 0):

I can think of two options, depending on exactly how the two applications interact.

1. Check if B is installed. If not, redirect the user to Google Play to install it. Then use Intents in A to communicate with B.
2. If you have the source code for B available, move the shared code to a Android Library project, call it C. Then update both A and B to import C and use its code directly.